# Upgrade SonarQube to 5.2 fails with java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: null

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube5.2

I've tried to upgrade SonarQube from 5.0 to 5.2, that failed so I've run upgrade from 5.0 through all intermediate versions up to 5.1.2 - all of them succeeded, but upgrade from 5.1.2 to 5.2 failed again with the same error.

I haven't found anywhere similar question reported, so asking here for help what can be wrong and how to fix it.

```
2015.12.14 16:54:33 ERROR web[o.s.s.s.IndexQueue] Could not execute normalization for stack
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: null
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:121) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
   at org.sonar.server.search.IndexQueue.processActionsIntoQueries(IndexQueue.java:119) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.search.IndexQueue.enqueue(IndexQueue.java:83) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.db.DbSession.commit(DbSession.java:61) [sonar-db-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.db.BaseDao.synchronizeAfter(BaseDao.java:329) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.db.BaseDao.synchronizeAfter(BaseDao.java:315) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.search.IndexSynchronizer.synchronize(IndexSynchronizer.java:107) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.search.IndexSynchronizer.executeDeprecated(IndexSynchronizer.java:74) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup$1.doPrivileged(PlatformLevelStartup.java:81) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:45) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.start(PlatformLevelStartup.java:78) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:197) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:114) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:99) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration.doRestartContainer(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:137) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration.doDatabaseMigration(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:113) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration.access$000(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:37) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration$1.run(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:100) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
2015.12.14 16:54:33 TRACE web[sql] time=62ms | sql=select 1
2015.12.14 16:54:33 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB migration failed | time=1274473ms
2015.12.14 16:54:33 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB Migration or container restart failed. Process ended with an exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute normalization for stack
   at org.sonar.server.search.IndexQueue.processActionsIntoQueries(IndexQueue.java:138) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.search.IndexQueue.enqueue(IndexQueue.java:83) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.db.DbSession.commit(DbSession.java:61) ~[sonar-db-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.db.BaseDao.synchronizeAfter(BaseDao.java:329) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.db.BaseDao.synchronizeAfter(BaseDao.java:315) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.search.IndexSynchronizer.synchronize(IndexSynchronizer.java:107) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.search.IndexSynchronizer.executeDeprecated(IndexSynchronizer.java:74) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup$1.doPrivileged(PlatformLevelStartup.java:81) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:45) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.start(PlatformLevelStartup.java:78) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:197) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:114) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:99) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration.doRestartContainer(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:137) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration.doDatabaseMigration(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:113) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration.access$000(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:37) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration$1.run(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:100) [sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: null
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:121) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
   at org.sonar.server.search.IndexQueue.processActionsIntoQueries(IndexQueue.java:119) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
   ... 19 common frames omitted
```

SonarQube runs on Windows 7, Java 1.8.0_66, 64-bit,
Microsoft SQL server 10.50.4000.0 runs on another server.